# Why does my Azure Function App, which generates PDF files from data, time out?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function App in Visual Studio 2019 on .NET Core 2.1.  My Function takes a set of data (less than 1 MB) and generates a PDF report of the data based on an HTML template (using the NuGet package [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf)).

The function is triggered by an Azure Service Bus Queue.

It works perfectly when I run the function app locally, with my local.settings.json pointing to the queue on Azure.  I send a message to the queue and everything works/completes as expected within a matter of seconds.  But when I deploy it to Azure and when it is triggered, it times out during the PDF generation process after working for several minutes.  Everything else works up until it reaches this block of code (after the LogInformation() call):

```
                _log.LogInformation("Converting template and content into PDF file...");
                pdf = Pdf
                    .From(content)
                    .OfSize(PaperSize.A4)
                    .WithoutOutline()
                    .WithMargins(1.25.Centimeters())
                    .Portrait()
                    .Comressed()
                    .Content();
                _log.LogInformation("Finished converting template and content into PDF file");
```

It never reaches the second LogInformation("Finished....") call, timing out before that point while executing the Pdf calls.

Here is a sample of the App Insights log (first my logged message, then the timeout exception):

```
12/4/2019, 2:30:18.351 PM   Converting template and content into PDF file...    1   trace   {"prop__{OriginalFormat}":"Converting template and content into PDF file...","HostInstanceId":"fe52d18f-9830-40bc-a92b-f0a90cf37dc9","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction.User","LogLevel":"Information","ProcessId":"4456","InvocationId":"cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b"}     PDFProcessorFunction    3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe    |3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe.60bad8bb00011f46.     PC  0.0.0.0 df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev    c8ddc12737b5c414811dd541ac7507946788a5bbd653984da9e4a88632659933    9f5886c8-fb23-4ef3-a0af-5cb7333f460e    df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev    7a528756-2a38-4511-8b8d-04365870a91c    azurefunctions: 2.0.12888.0 87ec212c-16cc-11ea-888f-5f9ca4eaab67    1   

timestamp [UTC]
2019-12-04T19:30:18.351427Z

message
Converting template and content into PDF file...

severityLevel
1

itemType
trace
customDimensions
{"prop__{OriginalFormat}":"Converting template and content into PDF file...","HostInstanceId":"fe52d18f-9830-40bc-a92b-f0a90cf37dc9","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction.User","LogLevel":"Information","ProcessId":"4456","InvocationId":"cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b"}

operation_Name
PDFProcessorFunction

12/4/2019, 2:35:14.307 PM   Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Id: 'cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b'). Initiating cancellation.    3   trace   {"prop__{OriginalFormat}":"Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Id: 'cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b'). Initiating cancellation.","HostInstanceId":"fe52d18f-9830-40bc-a92b-f0a90cf37dc9","LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction","ProcessId":"4456","InvocationId":"cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b"}        PDFProcessorFunction    3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe    |3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe.60bad8bb00011f46.     PC  0.0.0.0 df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev    c8ddc12737b5c414811dd541ac7507946788a5bbd653984da9e4a88632659933    9f5886c8-fb23-4ef3-a0af-5cb7333f460e    df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev    7a528756-2a38-4511-8b8d-04365870a91c    azurefunctions: 2.0.12888.0 32061e7c-16cd-11ea-ae75-6364d66f68e2    1   

timestamp [UTC]
2019-12-04T19:35:14.307144Z

message
Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Id: 'cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b'). Initiating cancellation.

severityLevel
3

itemType
trace
customDimensions
{"prop__{OriginalFormat}":"Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Id: 'cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b'). Initiating cancellation.","HostInstanceId":"fe52d18f-9830-40bc-a92b-f0a90cf37dc9","LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction","ProcessId":"4456","InvocationId":"cab3b347-95d3-45ff-b24d-c7c5048e6a6b"}

operation_Name
PDFProcessorFunction

operation_Id
3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe

operation_ParentId
|3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe.60bad8bb00011f46.

client_Type
PC

client_IP
0.0.0.0

cloud_RoleName
df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev

cloud_RoleInstance
c8ddc12737b5c414811dd541ac7507946788a5bbd653984da9e4a88632659933

appId
9f5886c8-fb23-4ef3-a0af-5cb7333f460e

appName
df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev

iKey
7a528756-2a38-4511-8b8d-04365870a91c

sdkVersion
azurefunctions: 2.0.12888.0

itemId
32061e7c-16cd-11ea-ae75-6364d66f68e2

itemCount
1
```

And here are the actual timeout exception details:

```
12/4/2019, 2:09:01.106 PM   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException   Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: PDFProcessorFunction    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext   3   [{"severityLevel":"Error","outerId":"0","message":"Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: PDFProcessorFunction","parsedStack":[{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext","level":0,"line":660,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":1,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":2,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":3,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":4,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__27.MoveNext","level":5,"line":576,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":7,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":9,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext","level":10,"line":532,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":11,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":12,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":13,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":14,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__25.MoveNext","level":15,"line":468,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":16,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":17,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":18,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":19,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext","level":20,"line":278,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":21,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext","level":22,"line":322,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":23,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":24,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":25,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":26,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext","level":27,"line":117,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"}],"type":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException","id":"15999211"}]  exception   {"FormattedMessage":"Executed 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Failed, Id=6b0cebaa-0876-428d-a324-03265563651b)","HostInstanceId":"d7abe331-beea-4165-86b4-0323f307939a","InvocationId":"6b0cebaa-0876-428d-a324-03265563651b","ProcessId":"5856","LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction"} PDFProcessorFunction    3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe    |3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe.30b1b04f0e993f4a. PC  0.0.0.0 df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev    34c90aa5d115bbf81d1cb11cf8ef01321f11d527a73c6ae5f86ec717cb94c776    

timestamp [UTC]
2019-12-04T19:09:01.1061419Z

problemId
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext

type
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException

assembly
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

method
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext

outerType
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException

outerMessage
Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: PDFProcessorFunction

outerAssembly
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

outerMethod
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext

severityLevel
3
details
[{"severityLevel":"Error","outerId":"0","message":"Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: PDFProcessorFunction","parsedStack":[{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext","level":0,"line":660,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":1,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":2,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":3,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":4,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__27.MoveNext","level":5,"line":576,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":7,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":9,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext","level":10,"line":532,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":11,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":12,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":13,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":14,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__25.MoveNext","level":15,"line":468,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":16,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":17,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":18,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":19,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext","level":20,"line":278,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":21,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext","level":22,"line":322,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":23,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":24,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":25,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":26,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext","level":27,"line":117,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"}],"type":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException","id":"15999211"}]

itemType
exception
customDimensions
{"FormattedMessage":"Executed 'PDFProcessorFunction' (Failed, Id=6b0cebaa-0876-428d-a324-03265563651b)","HostInstanceId":"d7abe331-beea-4165-86b4-0323f307939a","InvocationId":"6b0cebaa-0876-428d-a324-03265563651b","ProcessId":"5856","LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Function.PDFProcessorFunction"}

operation_Name
PDFProcessorFunction

operation_Id
3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe

operation_ParentId
|3f325922eef58b46b2f635d283deeebe.30b1b04f0e993f4a.

client_Type
PC

client_IP
0.0.0.0

cloud_RoleName
df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev

cloud_RoleInstance
34c90aa5d115bbf81d1cb11cf8ef01321f11d527a73c6ae5f86ec717cb94c776

appId
9f5886c8-fb23-4ef3-a0af-5cb7333f460e

appName
df-eo-pdf-queue-function-dev

iKey
7a528756-2a38-4511-8b8d-04365870a91c

sdkVersion
azurefunctions: 2.0.12888.0

itemId
88417461-16c9-11ea-9da1-1b43f8d3fcf0

itemCount
1
```

And yes, I have tried increasing the timeout value (up to our service plan's maximum of 10 minutes) - but it still times out.  Even though it only takes a few seconds to execute on my local machine.

In addition, I have checked, double-checked, triple-checked all the Function App configuration settings.  (I should mention that my company has several other Azure Function Apps written in .NET Core 2.1 that work fine).

What am I doing wrong?  Is is simply that Azure Functions are not meant to handle resource-intensive operations such as generating PDFs?

Comment: Are you hosting your function in a App Service plan or Consumption plan? Do you change the timeout value on host.json file?

Comment: Have you watched the monitors or app insights to see if your function is not 
exceeding the ACUs?

Comment: If you are using a consumption plan, try provisioning the function under an App Service Plan with a healthy sized App Service. Looking at the service limits for consumption plans, the max memory is 1.5GB and some reasonable ACUs. But it never hurts to try and see what happens.

Comment: I test this package with the v2 function, it could work after [3 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9TcN.png). So what's your service plan, please change the timeout value to the max. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).

Comment: @GeorgeChen our company has a consumption plan.

Comment: So try to increase it to 10 minutes.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Comment: @GeorgeChen I already tried increasing the timeout to 10 minutes (the max allowed); it still times out after running for 10 minutes.  At this point, I'm assuming that I'll need to convince the higher-ups to switch to an app service plan.  Someone had also suggested using Durable Functions.  Do you think that would make a difference?

Comment: My thought is to scale up or scale out the app service - but the problem is that both the Scale Up and Scale Out icons are grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem which also demands intensive CPU. Seems to me that the problem is something in the Azure Functions side. What you can do is use a Durable Functions and pass this PDF generation to an activity. I am not sure if it will solve for you or not, but worths a try.